# using media pipe (facemesh) to adjust 3D model from face landmark question

Tags: mediapipe

all these months we were trying to research on how to generate a 3D mesh from a face picture and we have tried many options until we discovered media pipe and we are very happy with it.
though we have not tried it yet as our devs are mostly C++ and need to review on python, but we are getting there.
Anyways, as I read thru using mediapipe we can extract the depth and face landmark of a face image and this is what we need,

we are also planning to prepare a 3D mesh that will adjust or "morph" base from the landmarks extracted from media pipe, however,  we are confuse of what will this 3D mesh will initial look or what the vertices of the mesh will begin from, where or what will the coordinates of the 3D mesh be base from, say for example, if the landmark in Media pipe gives us an X,Y and Z coordinate of the tip of the nose, where or what is the base of that XYZ landmark coordinates from, we need to know which 3D space the landmark is from so we can match it with the initial pose of the 3D mesh that we need to prepare.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?